# How to resize an animated gif with ImageMagick (php)?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif

I cannot find a working example. This one is not working, it's not animated:

```
$imagick = new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$format = $imagick->getImageFormat();
if ($format == 'GIF') {
  $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();
  do {
     $imagick->resizeImage(500, 500, Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);
  } while ($imagick->nextImage());
  $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
  $imagick->writeImages($name, true);

}

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick command line, this works for me

Original Animation:

[image]

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce -resize 500x500 -layers optimize -loop 0 resize.gif
```

[image]

Did you do the equivalent of -coalesce after reading your input animation? Did you do the optimize step after resizing?

Sorry, I do not use PHP Imagick or any other API.